# formatting non-English numbers

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using a func to format the numbers (separate thousands) inside UITextField while the user is typing. It's ok while the keyboard is Eng but when the keyboard changes Farsi it does nothing. my codes:

```
override func viewdidload(){
        self.mainTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)

}
```

and:

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == self.mainTextField {

            // Some locales use different punctuations.
            var textFormatted = textField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
            textFormatted = textFormatted?.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")

            let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal

            if let text = textFormatted, let textAsInt = Int(text) {
                textField.text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: textAsInt))
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't set the separators directly. Use `locale` property instead.

Comment: You can use L10n-swift pod. But if you do not use external libraries then you need to set `locale` property for `NumberFormatter`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I am not pretty sure of the purpose of implementing:

```
// Some locales use different punctuations.
var textFormatted = textField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
textFormatted = textFormatted?.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")
```

However, you would need to set the desired [locale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale) of NumberFormatter. Example:

```
let text = "123456"

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa")
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal

if let textAsInt = Int(text), let output = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: textAsInt)) {
    print(output) // "۱۲۳٬۴۵۶"
}
```

Referring to what implemented above, `output` would be a string containing Farsi numbers ("۱۲۳٬۴۵۶"), no matter what is the given text ("123456").

---

**UPDATE:**

If the case is: the given input is Farsi number and the desired output is English number, you could do it like this:

```
let text = "۱۲۳٬۴۵۶"

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal

if let textAsInt = numberFormatter.number(from: text)?.intValue, let output = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: textAsInt)) {
    print(output) // "123,456"
}
```

Comment: u know the reason of removing punctuations is that when u reach the fourth character u will see sth like "1,234" and this is not sth that can be re-formatted.by the way the NumberFormatter doesn't seem to be able to format farsi numbers so i decided to convert them to english first and convert them to farsi again at the last stage(output)

Comment: the answer doesn't fulfill the question. it explains two scenarios but my scenario is when text = "۱۲۳۴۵۶" and output should be "۱۲۳,۴۵۶" which doesn't work with the given code